# Make a class of type SKNode in swift

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

Im trying to make a class in swift that will be of type sknode that will also contain a parameter holding a position. I keep getting an error trying to create the class saying "initializer does not override a designated initializer from its super class" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how the class is supposed to be created.

```
import Foundation

import SpriteKit
class hud:SKNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(position:CGPoint){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `"initializer does not override a designated initializer from its super class"` error since you have marked your init(position: CGPoint) initializer as override.
SKNode has no such initializer so there is nothing to override.

Simply removing the override will rid you of the error, and your Hud class will have an initializer taking a CGPoint as a parameter.

`init(position: CGPoint) {...}`

It's worth noting that SKNode already has a property called position of type CGPoint, so it's possible that SKNode already have the capabilities you are after. Otherwise you'll likely want to call your property something else (such as myPosition) to avoid clashing with the existing property.

Comment: but then i get another error saying Super.init isnt called before returning initializer when i remove the overide thing

Comment: hey. I also have another question regarding the menu class if you can answer. here is the link to it    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237669/sknode-cant-see-added-children

Answer (score 1):

Remove the override keyword and don't forget to call the original initializer in your init method:

```
class hud:SKNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(position:CGPoint){
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, i also have another question if you can answer it about instantiating the hud class in the main method, and adding sprites to the class. heres the link to the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237669/sknode-cant-see-added-children