# sknode can't see added children

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

Here i created a menu class which contains a few items. I want to display these sprites in the main class. I experimented with this by creating an object associating with the sknode class in the touches began method, but when i added the menu object in the main class using the addChild thing, nothing showed up.

```
class menu:SKNode {
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"background") 
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(){
        super.init()
         var fixedSize = self.frame.width/11
    background.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.width-fixedSize, self.frame.size.height-fixedSize)
    background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(background)
    }
}


 //In the main method i said let settings = menu()  self.addChild(settings)   nothing shows up
```

Comment: Why are you defining a background size and position? because the "background" isn't created anywhere

Comment: sorry, i meant to spell "background" not button under the first bracket of the menu class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frame` property of an `SKNode` is equal to `CGRectZero`, so when you try to set the size of your background node it will also end up as `CGRectZero`.

An easy fix to your problem would be to add custom initializer and call that with the size of the scene.

```
class menu:SKNode {
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"background") 
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init()
        var fixedSize = size.width/11
        background.size = CGSizeMake(size.width-fixedSize, size.height-fixedSize)
        background.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Comment: also in my touches began method in the main class i created a conditional that checks a sprite in the menu class if it has been touched. I said"if settingsButton.background.containsPoint(touchLocation) {print("asdfa")}" nothing happens when i click on the background when it shows up

Comment: How are you determining touchLocation?

Comment: i said                     let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

Comment: i just figured it out, i said touch.locationInNode(menu!)